# SDA line pulled low by slave always?

Tags: i2c

If due to some problem in slave, The slave is not able to leave the SDA line free , so that master can gain control over it. Its gets low by the slave in between data transfer , but not able to release it.

In this kind of situation how the controller can gain access of SDA line to again start some  communication?

Comment: It can't, simple as that.

Comment: What is the slave device? A link to its datasheet would help us answer your question.

Comment: Its a EEPROM CAV24c32 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slave may be stuck in a bad state. Out of sync with master. Try sending out some clocks to advance the slave state machine to a different state. This happens frequently with I2C during boot up and power cycle type of situations. But there could also be some underlying problem. For example, your clock may be ringing, and this could cause the problem. (The clock may be registering as two clocks) So you should put an oscilloscope on the bus and make sure the signal levels and signal integrity look reasonable. Make sure your clock frequency is not too fast, also.

The CAV24C32 uses so little power, you could actually power it from an IO on the master if you have an extra pin. If you drive the power IO low, then make sure all other lines connected to the EEPROM are also low, that will completely reset it.